# Sublime text 3 stopped compiling python programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sublimetext3

My sublime text 3 has suddenly stopped compiling my python scripts. I am trying to run the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print ('hellow world')


from numpy import*
```

The output is:

```
3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
hellow world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mq10000477/Dropbox/9.0 3D field sensing/2.0 python/2D_dephasing_4_qubits_optimise.py", line 12, in <module>
    from numpy import*
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/usr/local/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

The is a file in the build system folder for python3:

```
{
     "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

However, when I try to run from terminal

```
python3 
from numpy import*
```

Then there's no error.
What's happening here/or what happened? I've been debugging this for hours with no avail.

Comment: Your numpy is for arm (m1) architecture , not x86-64 as the error states:
`'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))`

Comment: Thank you! But it works when I run it from terminal - why would that be the case?

Comment: I imagine you likely may have more than one numpy and maybe whole python3 env installed, and when launching presumably from Finder or alike it picks the wrong one.